# Bones losing their weights in random parts. Can't figure out why

Tags: bones

so when I put the rig in my character and did automatic weights everything worked accordingly. But since I started messing with my vertice groups and adjusting the weights, it all started messing up. My right side arm completely disconnected from the characters arm and the upper part of the thigh is disconnected to. I've been going back and forth from the mesh to the weight painting and vertice groups and can't figure out why. Any help?

Comment: if you go in Weight Paint mode, you can see for example that your right arm has no weight, so you must have made a mistake somewhere. Either reparent your mesh, or correct it in Weight Paint mode, or with the Vertex Groups of the Data panel. Also it's strange to give your Spline003 an IK constraint, but maybe you have your reasons...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I have the right arm painted in my vertex group, but do you know why it wouldn't appear in the weight paint mode like it would anything else? I'm going to go ahead and fix it in weight paint mode, but I just want to understand why it wouldn't work the first time.

Comment: sorry I don't remember, I don't have your file anymore